# What is the purpose of the inverted cone at the center of a Starship thrust puck?

Tags: spacex-starship

In the center of the Starhip's thrust puck, where the lowest portion of the LOX tank should be, there is a heavily reinforced inverted cone. Why is it there? Why not just complete the tank in a regular shape?

[image: thrust puck inverted nosecone]

Image: https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=52205.msg2150205#msg2150205

Edit: What I mean by inverted cone v. "regular" shape:

[image]

Comment: See edited answer - there is a schematic describing what I mean

Comment: Thanks, I don't know enough about the vehicle to know whether the cone was pointing up or down, your sketch makes it clear.

Comment: I am sticking by the nomenclature I found - I agree in a way there is nothing inverted about the cone :D

Comment: IIRC, the cylinder on top of that cone is the fuel pipe from the Methane tank, so maybe this is a structural decision to use the fuel pipe as a load-bearing member.

Comment: I just had the opposite idea - maybe the cone is there to support to long, heavy methane down comer tube...

Comment: I don't suppose there's a mating surface with a positive cone, thus using these for alignment during assembly?